# Trying to get data based on ID ( using kendo UI datasources)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have 2 datasources :

datasource1 : gets general data for the page and contains a **specific Id** for this page .

```
editDataSource: new kendo.ui.HREditorDataSource({
        readController: "Notification",
        readAction: "GetTemplate",
        updateController: "Notification",
        updateAction: "UpdateTemplate",
        createController: "Notification",
        createAction: "CreateTemplate",
        sort: [
            { field: "Code", dir: "desc" }
        ],
        schema:kendoHelpers.buildDefaultSchema({
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: {
                    editable: true,
                    nullable: false,
                    type: "string"
                },
                Code:{
                    editable: true,
                    nullable: false,
                    type: "string"
                },
                Subject:{
                    editable: true,
                    nullable: false,
                    type: "string"
                },
                Body:{
                    editable: true,
                    nullable: true,
                    type: "string",
                    validation: { required: false }
                },
                TS: {
                    editable: false,
                    nullable: false,
                    type: "date"
                }
            }
        }),
```

datasource2 : i want to bring the right images based on the **Current Id**

how can i connect the id that i get from datasource1 with the call that i will make to server on datasource2?

so i get the images for this specific id
possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The [datasource read method](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/read) has an optional data parameter that you can populate to pass data to the remote service.

so you could do something like (broken into two lines for readability):

```
var currentIdData = { currentId: [get your current id here] };
dataSource2.read(currentIdData);
```